# DataSourceRequest is not deserializing for a WebAPI Get method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, kendo-grid, angular5

I am trying to call a WebAPI method from Angular 5 like this:

```
selectClaims(state: DataSourceRequestState):Observable<DataResult>
{
    return this.http.get<GridDataResult>(`${this.apiUrl}/SelectClaims?${toDataSourceRequestString(state)}`);
}
```

Which calls the API method as expected. The API method is:

```
    [Route("SelectClaims")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult SelectClaims([FromUri][DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest ClaimsRequest)
        {
        if(ClaimsRequest == null)
            ClaimsRequest=new DataSourceRequest { Page=1, PageSize=20 };
        var result = _db.Claims.ToDataSourceResult(ClaimsRequest, c => { c.SortHistory(); return c; });
        return Ok(result);
        }
```

The trouble is that ClaimsRequest only de-serializes Page and PageSize correctly. Filters and Sorts don't come through:

Fiddler tells me that the URL from Angular is:
`GET /api/v1/Claims/SelectClaims?filter=id~eq~2&page=1&sort=firstName-asc&pageSize=20 HTTP/1.1`, but in the controller both filter and sort are null.

If I create a URL through Swagger like: 'http://localhost:50223/api/v1/Claims/SelectClaims?ClaimsRequest.page=1&ClaimsRequest.pageSize=11&ClaimsRequest.sorts=firstName-desc' I do see a sort array in the API method, but the "Member" field is null.

Any attempt to add a filter through Swagger like 'http://localhost:50223/api/v1/Claims/SelectClaims?ClaimsRequest.page=1&ClaimsRequest.pageSize=11&ClaimsRequest.filters=id~eq~2' results in a "Cannot create an instance of an interface." error.

The state is a `DataSourceRequestState` in the angular component from a Kendo Grid for Angular.

I have simulated this in a simple test program and everything works fine there. The only difference in my test program is that the API controller targets .Net Core and the real system targets .Net 4.6.1.

Do I have to de-serialize manually in .Net 4.6.1 for some reason, or is something else going on here?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have the same issue

Comment: It's been a while, but I think the answer was that the method should not have [HttpGet] because Telerik is using a Post method for the request (even tough it looks like it should be a Get). Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi John, yes it does, I figured out the same thing after running the MVC version and saw that adding "aspmvc-api" to the type switched the call from GET to POST. Awful Documentation. I ended up making a new object which the same parameters as a DataSourceRequest with [FromUri] and that worked a charm (Needed it to run on GET). I had to map the filters and sorts again but I would have to touch them anyway as my VM properties do not match the entity so the search would fail. Tks for getting back!

Answer (score 0):

It should be a POST not a GET. Something like this:

```
return this.http.post<GridDataResult>(`${this.apiUrl}/SelectClaims`, toDataSourceRequestString(state)});
```

I needed it to be a GET (URL) so i created a new object

```
public class GridParamaterBinder
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public string Filter { get; set; }
    public string Sort { get; set; }

    public DataSourceRequest ToDataSourceRequest(IConfigurationProvider mapper, Func<string, string> OverDefaultParamaterMapping)
    {
        DataSourceRequest result = new DataSourceRequest();

        result.Page = Page;
        result.PageSize = PageSize;
        result.Sorts = GridDescriptorSerializer.Deserialize<SortDescriptor>(Sort);
        result.Filters = FilterDescriptorFactory.Create(Filter);

        return result;
    }
}
```

and used it instead of the Telerik effort.

in API I Bind it like so

```
public virtual DataSourceResult Get([FromUri]GridParamaterBinder request)
```

And then used it like

```
DataSourceResult results = query.ToDataSourceResult(request.ToDataSourceRequest(),  r => (r)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @KevDevMan for your solution. I found this [example](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-examples-asp-net-mvc/tree/master/grid-data-source-request-web-api), 
then I changed my API controller like this and it worked like a charm :

```cs
[HttpGet, Route("for-kendo-grid")]
public DataSourceResult GetProducts([System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinder(typeof(WebApiDataSourceRequestModelBinder))] DataSourceRequest request)
```

explanation [here](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/the-facts-on-using-kendo-ui-with-asp-net-webapi)